# Why expression (12 + 5) / 10 * 10 evaluates different results in Pycharm (Python 3.6.7) and CodingBat (Python 3.x)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**(12+5)/10*10** evaluates to **17.0** in Pycharm(Python 3.6.7) and same expression evaluates to **10** in CodingBat(Python 3.x). According to this question([BODMAS - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286140/bodmas-python/53247911#53247911)), Pycharm is right?

Comment: One of them is not Python 3.

Comment: Pycharm is running 3.6.7 and I am sure that coding bat is also running 3.x.

Comment: Took a look at CodingBat.  Doesn't seem to list what version of Python it's using.  It would seem to be Python 2.x from what you found.  `/` is integer (floor) division in Python2, and float division in Python3.

Comment: And how it will evaluate in python 2?

Comment: Got it. Thank you!!